# If C99 lifted "variable declaration at top of block" constraint, why doing so in a "for loop" showing error?

Tags: c, for-loop, c99, variable-declaration

I read from a site that C99 lifted the restriction that variables in C must be declared at the top of a block. I tested in my program below and it is indeed true as I get no errors. But in th e same program if I declare a variable in the first statement of a `for` loop, I get the error:

`'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode|`

Two things here. Since it is indeed allowed to declare variables in the middle of the program,as I did for `i`, why then I am not allowed to do that in a `for` loop statement? And second, if my compiler (Codeblocks/gcc) is not in C99 mode already, why didn't I get an error when I declared variables in the middle instead of the top?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
  //Proof that initialization in middle works (for i)
  printf("Enter\n");
  char string[20];
  scanf("%s", string);
  int i=20;
  printf("%s,%i", string, i);
  //Proved that it works

  for(int j=0; j<10; j++) //THIS IS NOT ALLOWED
    printf("%d\n", j);
}
```

Comment: Because the default mode for your compiler is _not_ in C99 mode. Try adding `-std=c99` flag to GCC.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg If so,why then I don't get an error while declaring variables in middle as I successfully did for `i`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg A pre-C99 setting would show that as an error,shouldn't it?

Comment: @Jugni Do you compile with many error checking if you compile with -Wall -Wextra -pedantic it will probably show that i is not on top of the scope

Comment: If you give gcc the `-pedantic` flag it will *warn* you about *mixed declarations and code* (and the comments). And if you compile with `-Wall` it'll be angry with you for not explicitly returning a value.

Comment: As hinted to in earlier comments, it's useful to compile with extra warnings. Me, for example, always have at least `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` to get as many warnings as possible. It helps me find cases where the code is syntactically and semantically correct but otherwise may cause problems (undefined behavior or logical errors). Enabling warnings, and fixing them, will make the code better.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg If in pre-C99 we can only declare variables at top of a block,what if **inside** that block,we declare variables but in a nested block,enclosed in `{}`.Will it violate the condition as though we might be following the rule by declaring it at top of nested block,we are still defying the rule by declaring variables in middle of the outer block!!Please clarify this.

Comment: That is okay. For example `for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) { int some_var = 5; use_some_var(some_var); }`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks for your reply and not frowning upon my trivial questions.I really needed the details.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get into C99 mode in Codeblocks10.05?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12152067/how-to-get-into-c99-mode-in-codeblocks10-05)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default gcc compiles code with its own "dialect" which is an extension of C89. It is probably a good idea for new code and especially anybody learning C nowadays to pass to more modern and standardized version of the language. Unfortunately their implementation of C11 isn't yet complete, so you'd have to stick with C99 for the moment using `-std=c99`.

The gcc [online documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/) has information on the different dialects of C they implement.

An alternative compiler could be clang which is C99 by default. To my experience it is often better suited for beginners because the diagnostics are a bit more user friendly than gcc's.

Comment: If in pre-C99 we can only declare variables at top of a block,what if **inside** that block,we declare variables but in a nested block,enclosed in `{}`.Will it violate the condition as though we might be following the rule by declaring it at top of nested block,we are still defying the rule by declaring variables in middle of the outer block!!

Comment: @Jugni, the rule was that you could declare a variable at the beginning of *its* block. (Otherwise this would have made not much sense.) But really, don't think too much about older versions of C and try to use the modern one with the features it provides.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this basic question.I am fussy about details and hence your answer really helped.

Comment: The specific GCC quirk causing confusion is in [2.1. C Language](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.3.0/gcc/Standards.html#index-C-standard-21):  "Some features that are part of the C99 standard are accepted as extensions in C90 mode, and some features that are part of the C11 standard are accepted as extensions in C90 and C99 modes."  GCC allows some of the conveniences of modern C standards, even when compiling earlier versions of C.  More details in [3.4. Options Controlling C Dialect](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.3.0/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#C-Dialect-Options).

Answer (score 3):

You use gcc : That enable some gcc specific extensions by default. Try :

```
[igmar@devel ~]$ gcc -std=c89 -pedantic -o xxx xxx.c
xxx.c: In function 'main':
xxx.c:6: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code
xxx.c:8: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code
```

-pedantic disabled the non-standard gcc extensions.

Comment: Thanks for running the program and sharing the warnings.Seems like you too are new to StackOverflow like me!!+1