# Code to print the no of elements in an array gives one less than the no of elements

Tags: c, pointers

I've written a code to find the number of elements in an integer array as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {2, 3, 5, 5};    
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        printf("%d %d\n", &arr[i], arr[i]);
    }

    printf("%d", &arr[i - 1] - arr);

    return 0;
}
```

The last `printf` prints `3` as opposed to `4` which is the number of elements in the array. Why does the code print one less than the no of elements in the array?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: can you show the full output? "its coming 3" has no meaning in this plane of existence

Comment: you have 4 numbers `1,2,3,4` , when you write `4-1` it is equal to `3` , you must write `4-1+1` for it , another example : `5,6,7,8` answer is `8-5+1` equals to `4`

Comment: Usual way to do for an arrays is: `sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array)`.

Comment: @andriy i think this would not work with `double` array.

Comment: @jackjay, have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You pass the wrong format specifier to `printf`. So whatever output you get in the loop is the result of undefined behavior. To print a pointer correctly and portably you must use the `%p` specifier and pass a `void*`:

```
printf("%p %d\n", (void*)&arr[i], arr[i]);
```

The reason the last `printf` prints 3 (even though the format specifier is maybe wrong again), is because that's the offset between the the last cell in the array and the beginning. That's what you calculate, so remember that the last cell is indexed with offset `3`.

The result of subtracting two pointers can be captured in the type [`ptrdiff_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/ptrdiff_t). And to print that you'd need the `%td` format specifier, if we are to make your code more portable again:

```
printf("%td", &arr[i-1]-arr);
```

To calculate the array length, you'd need to subtract a pointer to "one passed the end" element of the array (don't worry, calculating that address is not undefined behavior) and a pointer to the beginning. Applying that to the print statement after your loop

```
printf("%td", (arr + i) - arr);
```

Which quite expectantly, is just `i` (4).

Comment: this is not the OP ! his question is about this line : `printf("%d",&arr[i-1]-arr);`

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi `%d` is  not appropriate for addresses.

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックス, and how addresses are involved here? It's a length between them, which can fit some integer.

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックス i know , i just wanted to warn about main question of `op`

Comment: @0andriy look inside the `for` loop.

Comment: He doesn't print an address. He prints the number of elements between `arr` element i-1 and `arr` element 0. That is always an integer. The `%td` specifier is wrong.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie - `ptrdiff_t` is the only portable way to hold a "pointer difference", and the format specifier for it is `%td`. Before you claim anything is "wrong", I suggest you consult the standard, or at the very least cppreference.

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi - I always reserve the right to answer about all points in the OP I see relevant. Seeing as I covered every transgression I deemed relevant (including that last print statement) I fail to see how I didn't answer the OP.

Comment: @StoryTeller, TBH, you did this on 5th+ iteration of your answer.

Comment: @0andriy - And? The SO model encourages iterative improvements of ones answer. I also did all 5 iterations in less than 6 minutes.

Comment: @StoryTeller, and he commented after your 1st or 2nd. Means you typing faster than *covering every transgression*.

Comment: @0andriy - I will type as fast as I feel comfortable to correctly convey my reasoning, not to appease trigger happy SO users.

Comment: First of all i would like to thank each and every one here.this was my first question on Stackoverflow and i didn't know that i will get  quick reponse.

Comment: @StoryTeller, I may be wrong, but a pointer difference or address difference would always be the number of bytes and `%td` would be appropriate, but here the calculation counts elements, not bytes. Were it, the answer would have been 12 (3 integers of 32 bits).

Comment: @PaulOgilvie - No. `ptrdiff_t` is not just for counting bytes (although it is the correct type to use as the signed counterpart of `size_t` for `char` pointers).

Comment: 1.when i use %td as format specifier,i get ouput printed 'td' and dont get any number.i am using codeblock IDE.

Comment: @Neerajgupta - Please follow the guideline here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12152067/how-to-get-into-c99-mode-in-codeblocks10-05

Comment: it's ok right now , my comment was before editing ;)

Comment: when i try to type ptrdiff_t my compiler doesnt recognise it even though i added header file <stddef.h>.

Comment: @Neerajgupta - The type is defined in this header, regardless of standard version being used ([see here in C90](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/93f801a243106ee2)), and is most definitely [defined in C99](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/73bbdc3f88d828b0). So if this doesn't work, you have a far more serious problem in your setup. One I cannot troubleshoot for you.

Comment: I, for one, think that it is good to address undefined behavior before other issues, since otherwise the behavior of the program is, well, undefined! +1 for spreading the word about correct types, conversion specifications, and length modifiers.

Answer (score 1):

Your last `printf` need correction for specifiers as in your case the difference in first and last position address can easily fit in `int` but caan produce undefined behaviour so use `td` specifier as difference in address is of `ptrdiff_t` type. The problem is that how you calculate your length of array, keep in mind that indexing is done from zero that is if you have array length of `4`, last index would be `3` and

```
array length according to your code is  3 - 0 = 3 

but actually it should be 3 - 0 + 1 = 4
```

change your outside `printf` to

```
printf("%td",&arr[i-1] - arr + 1);
```

I hope this would help you. Also you `printf` in your for loop needs correct specifier as you are trying to print the address instead of `int`.

Comment: what happened to me today.